# When I render my model in blender the only thing that appears is the blue color i have for the backround

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects

I've been trying to fix this for ages and can't seem to find a solution. I'm rendering with cycles. I've tried messing with the layers and different render engines and even tried finding a solution based on other questions but no luck.[image]

Here is the blend file

[image]

Comment: Without further information any answers would probably be guesses. Screenshots are very helpful and uploading your .blends to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is invauleable.

Comment: The only light in the scene is in a different layer than the one being rendered, you have a big box surrounding the scene with a white material being lit uniformly from all directions...

Comment: But I suspect you created the materials in blender internal and are trying to render in cycles without creating new materials.... that is just not going to work! **Materials from internal and Cycles are not interchangeable.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Object in your scene which is set to `Wireframe Display` mode in the viewport, but when rendered it is being shaded solid. It encompasses all your objects, so basically it hides everything. The object in question is called **CloudBounds**, and is highlighted in this screenshot:

[image: surrsounding box]

The camera however is clearly outside of this box:

[image: camera pos]

Probably you have tried to generate clouds using an Add-on which targets Blender Internal render engine? It would explain why there are no nodes on the cycles shader (it still has the button labeled `use nodes`):

[image]

Anyways, if you move that object to a separate layer which is not set as a RenderLayer, or simply hide or delete it, the scene renders again:

[image: set to not render the object]
[image: rendered scene]

Comment: Thank you so much, this problem was really confusing me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Everything renders properly now:)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have placed the camera at a positon, where it does not point at any geometry. Blender always renders through the active camera.

Hit NUMPAD-0 when your mouse cursor is over the 3D-viewport to look through your active camera.

Comment: I checked the camera and everything checks out